# If I cancel my amateur license, will my address be removed from the FCC database?

Tags: united-states, license, fcc

When my university encouraged me to apply for an amateur radio license, they never mentioned the fact that my address would be listed on the public FCC database, for anyone who Googles my name to easily see in the first few links.

I know that now that it's out there, it's probably already cached and can't be removed from the internet, because that's how the internet works. If someone wants to find my address, I want them to at least have to do *a little bit* of work, though. If I cancel my radio license, would the page listing my information, address included, at least be removed from the FCC website?

Comment: Probably not... you can also register a PO Box or some other address.  FCC doesn't require the address to be where you live, just somewhere you pick up mail.  Also, they will try email first if you register that.

Comment: @user10489 You can register a PO Box as your FCC license address? This useful fact needs to be publicized.

Comment: @比尔盖子 It's never been a secret, and there's never been anything official to suggest otherwise — some people just assume. Part 97 says that "The mailing address must be in an area where the amateur service is regulated by the FCC" (i.e. the US or US territory) and "where the grantee can receive mail delivery by the United States Postal Service". Not your home address, not the station location, just an address in the US where you can get mail.

Comment: Should have provided a different address? As a student, the dorm of that year? I agree that address leaking is not great.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your license is a matter of public record. As other have noted you can rent a PO box and use it as your address with the FCC. You required to maintain a postal address where the FCC can contact you.

Most of us use our home address. A few use a PO box. I have also heard of people who use a relative or friends address. I am not a lawyer and I am not 100% certain that the last option is legal, but as long as any letters from the FCC make their way to you in a timely fashion, I believe that it is OK.

On related note, when most people apply for their amateur radio license they put their Social Security Number on the application. While your SSN is not published like your address is, many people are not comfortable with handing their SSN to a group of strangers at the testing site. You can apply ahead of time to get a FRN number you can use instead. A FRN is assigned by FCC when you get your license, but you can get them ahead of time.

Here is a link, https://www.fcc.gov/wireless/support/universal-licensing-system-uls-resources/getting-fcc-registration-number-frn

by the way I am a Volunteer Examiner, one of those strange people you give you SSN to on your application. I have never heard of any VE using your SSN for anything except applying for your license.

Comment: Hello Jim, This doesn't really answer the question. The OP is asking "*If I cancel my radio license*, would the page listing my ... address ... be removed from the FCC website?"

Comment: @mikewaters this comes very close, I think, to answering the question.  For example, if you pull up any vanity license in the FCC database, the information for all prior holders is also there.  It is permanently in the public record.  A simple edit to clarify would be to prepend "No, it will not" to the beginning of this answer.

Comment: @ChrisK8NVH Thanks. It looks to me like your comment comes even closer to answering the question. If Jim doesn't reply or edit his answer, then why don't you post that as an answer here? :-)

Answer (score 3):

No.  As stated by @Jim your license is a matter of public record.  In fact, you can get a list of the names and addresses of all canceled amateur radio licenses at the FCC website: https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/searchAdvanced.jsp (choose Service Group "Amateur" and Status "Canceled").